# Current Latitude Longitude on Google Map

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, ios8, latitude-longitude

I am using below code to get current lat long in iOS 8.

.h

```
@interface DirectionViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate,GMSMapViewDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

.m

```
@synthesize locationManager;


    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
    // Configure the new event with information from the location
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];
    NSLog(@"dLatitude : %@", latitude);
    NSLog(@"dLongitude : %@",longitude);
```

But here, I am getting 0.00000 value for both latitude and longitude.
Can anybody help me here. How to get current lat long in iOS 8?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AppDelegte.h**

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
  CLLocation *currentLocation;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager             *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocationCoordinate;
```

**Appdelget.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init]; // initializing locationManager
    locationManager.delegate = self; // we set the delegate of locationManager to self.
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; // setting the accuracy

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

  CurrentLatitude=newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    CurrentLongitude=newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    NSLog(@"%f",CurrentLatitude);
    NSLog(@"%f",CurrentLongitude);
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}
```

**.Plsit add**

```
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the proper method to get your coordinates.

once you call `startUpdatingLocation`, it calls the location manager methods (that you must implement in order for this to work).

There are two of them, `[locationManager:didFailWithError:][1]`
 and `[-locationManager:didUpdateLocations:][2]`. You should have warnings asking you to add those methods in your .m, with the proper spelling if you haven't done it yet.

`didUpdateLocation` is called every X seconds and returns coordinates. You have to build your coordinate strings in this very specific method, where the coordinates are set.

From what I could gather,

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations

Will give you an array of CLLocation objects containing the location data.
This array always contains at least one object representing the current location. 
If updates were deferred or if multiple locations arrived before they could be delivered, the array may contain additional entries. 
The objects in the array are organized in the order in which they occurred. Therefore, the most recent location update is at the end of the array.
```

This means you'll have to get the `lastObject` of that array for the most recent location.

Here is an example i've found [on the web](http://www.devfright.com/didupdatelocations-ios-example/), for what the inside of that method could look. :

```
CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
    CLLocation *oldLocation;
    if (locations.count > 1) {
        oldLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:locations.count-2];
    } else {
        oldLocation = nil;
    }
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation %@ from %@", newLocation, oldLocation);
    MKCoordinateRegion userLocation = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(newLocation.coordinate, 1500.0, 1500.0);
    [regionsMapView setRegion:userLocation animated:YES];
```

Make sure to ask for the different permissions beforehand, and that you have them.
Also note that this method is only available since iOS5 and is different in the previous versions. Though it is very unlikely that you still support iOS5, I thought I should mention it.